# Android pjsip Tone generator (Dtmf) bug

Tags: java, android, pjsip

I have created a tone Generator function using pjsip library.

```
import org.pjsip.pjsua2.ToneDigit;
import org.pjsip.pjsua2.ToneDigitMapDigit;
import org.pjsip.pjsua2.ToneDigitMapVector;
import org.pjsip.pjsua2.ToneDigitVector;
import org.pjsip.pjsua2.ToneGenerator;

private static ToneGenerator toneGenerator;

 private boolean initToneGenerator() {
        try {
            toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator();
            toneGenerator.createToneGenerator();
            ToneDigitMapVector digitMap = new ToneDigitMapVector();
            ToneDigitMapDigit digit = new ToneDigitMapDigit();
            digit.setDigit("0");
            digit.setFreq1(941);
            digit.setFreq2(1336);
            digitMap.add(digit);
            digit.setDigit("1");
            digit.setFreq1(697);
            digit.setFreq2(1209);
            digitMap.add(digit);
            digit.setDigit("2");
            digit.setFreq1(697);
            digit.setFreq2(1336);
            digitMap.add(digit);
            digit.setDigit("3");
            digit.setFreq1(697);
            digit.setFreq2(1477);
            digitMap.add(digit);
            digit.setDigit("4");
            digit.setFreq1(770);
            digit.setFreq2(1209);
            digitMap.add(digit);
            digit.setDigit("5");
            digit.setFreq1(770);
            digit.setFreq2(1336);
            digitMap.add(digit);
            digit.setDigit("6");
            digit.setFreq1(770);
            digit.setFreq2(1477);
            digitMap.add(digit);
            digit.setDigit("7");
            digit.setFreq1(852);
            digit.setFreq2(1209);
            digitMap.add(digit);
            digit.setDigit("8");
            digit.setFreq1(852);
            digit.setFreq2(1336);
            digitMap.add(digit);
            digit.setDigit("9");
            digit.setFreq1(852);
            digit.setFreq2(1477);
            digitMap.add(digit);
            digit.setDigit("*");
            digit.setFreq1(941);
            digit.setFreq2(1209);
            digitMap.add(digit);
            digit.setDigit("#");
            digit.setFreq1(941);
            digit.setFreq2(1477);
            digitMap.add(digit);
            digit.setDigit("A");
            digit.setFreq1(697);
            digit.setFreq2(1633);
            digitMap.add(digit);
            digit.setDigit("B");
            digit.setFreq1(770);
            digit.setFreq2(1633);
            digitMap.add(digit);
            digit.setDigit("C");
            digit.setFreq1(852);
            digit.setFreq2(1633);
            digitMap.add(digit);
            digit.setDigit("D");
            digit.setFreq1(941);
            digit.setFreq2(1633);
            digitMap.add(digit);
            toneGenerator.setDigitMap(digitMap);
            // toneDigitVector = new ToneDigitVector();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The dtmf tones work properly , it's everything alright. The problem is that when I start a call (my `initToneGenerator()` is called) and the app stacks a little , then it autocloses and after this it's bringing back the calling screen.

I do not get any error , just the signal that the activity is restarted.

Comment: i think u r calling from different thread..so its getting null memory..